# SQL unique constraint on either of 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL that I would like to have a unique constraint so that any of two values cannot already exist.

for example if I have 2 columns, I would like it to not insert if the value in column B does not exist in column A or column B.

Is this possible and if so how is it done?

example:

```
Column A | Column B
--------------------
     4   |   6
```

I would want any object that tries to insert 4 or 6 not to be allowed into the table

Comment: Can't you just make some stored procedure that does a IF Exists() insert, instead of going with constraint?

Comment: please provide some sample data

Comment: @Veljko89 We are using EntityFramework on the back end that we call the sql from, so we want to avoid SP's as much as possible

Comment: @pancho018 see updated question

Comment: @LiamHT, consider a trigger.

Comment: Your first two sentences are mutually exclusive.  Which do you want?  New values in B that are required to be in A or B, or new values in B that are required *not* to be in A or B.

Comment: The problem with stored procedures and triggers is that SQL Server is designed to provide isolation between concurrent transactions so these "solutions" will fail in the case of concurrency. I would **strongly** recommend revisiting the data model to remove this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger with ROLLBACK TRANSACTION is the way to go.

```
create trigger dbo.something after insert as
begin
    if exists ( select * from inserted where ...check here if your data already exists... )
    begin
        rollback transaction
        raiserror ('some message', 16, 1)
    end
end
```

Comment: What if the insert was not done within a transaction?

Comment: A trigger operates as if there were an outstanding transaction in effect when the trigger is executed. This is true whether the statement firing the trigger is in an implicit or explicit transaction.

Comment: I've accepted your answer even though I have not done it. We have decided that the overhaul of adding a trigger is not worth the constraint that isn't 100% necessary, just a nice addition.

Comment: @Anton - fair enough, I didn't realise (or had forgotten) that!
In that case, my question should have been "what about if the trigger is fired in the context of a higher level transaction, where rolling back the _whole_ thing would be undesirable?"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which takes in these values & create a check constraint on it (referencing your functions return values) to your table.

```
create table t11 (Code int, code2 int)

create function fnCheckValues (@Val1 int, @Val2 int)
Returns int /*YOu can write a better implementation*/
as
Begin
 DECLARE @CntRow int  
 IF(@Val1 IS NULL OR @Val2 IS NULL) RETURN 0    
 select @CntRow = count(*)  from t11   
    where Code in (@Val1,@Val2 ) or Code2 in (@Val1,@Val2 ) 

 RETURN @CntRow  
End

GO

alter table t11 Add constraint CK_123 check ([dbo].[fnCheckValues]([Code],[code2])<=(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

When one want to enforce a multi-row constraint that is not offered by the database engine, the obvious solution is use of a trigger or stored procedure. This often does not work because the database isolates the transactions the triggers and stored procedures run in, allowing violations in the presense of concurrency.

Instead turn the constraint into something that the database engine will enforce.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T (A INT, B INT)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.T_Constraint_Helper (ColumnName sysname PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO dbo.T_Constraint_Helper (ColumnName)
VALUES ('A'), ('B')
GO

CREATE VIEW T_Constraint_VW 
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
SELECT CASE CH.ColumnName WHEN 'A' THEN T.A ELSE T.B END AS Value
FROM dbo.T
CROSS JOIN dbo.T_Constraint_Helper CH
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX FunnyConstraint_VW_UK ON dbo.T_Constraint_VW (Value)
GO

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, 2)
-- works
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2, 3)
-- Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
-- Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.T_Constraint_VW' with unique index 'T_Constraint_VW_UK'. The duplicate key value is (2).
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4, 4)
-- Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
-- Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.T_Constraint_VW' with unique index 'T_Constraint_VW_UK'. The duplicate key value is (4).
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5, 6)
-- works
```